# how to convert any datatype to our own created datatype

Tags: python-2.7

In function **add** i want to return l as matrix type. but i am able to return it only as list type.
My Aim is make m3 as matrix type and direclty want to display m3 as matrix which i have created **str**.

try:
    import sys

```
class matrix:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.file=a
        c=open(self.file,'r')
        self.list=c.readlines()
        self.row=len(self.list)
        self.col=len(self.list[1].split(" "))
        c.close
        templist=[]
        i=0
        j=0
        self.elements=[]
        while i<self.row:
            while j<self.col:
                templist=self.list[i].split(" ")
                self.elements.append(templist[j])
                j=j+1
            j=0
            i=i+1
        #return elem
    def __str__(self):
        #print self.file
        #print self.list
        s=''
        for x in self.list:
           s=s+x
        return s
    def __add__(self,other):
        #print self.elements
        #print other.elements
        i=0
        l=[]
        while i<len(self.elements):
            l.append(int(self.elements[i])+int(other.elements[i]))
            i=i+1
        #l=matrix(l)
        #print type(l)
        return l
    def write(self,sumlist,outputfile):
        #print sumlist
        #print outputfile
        fobj=open(outputfile,'w')
        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i<self.row:
            while j<self.col:
                fobj.writelines(str(sumlist[k])+" "),
                j=j+1
                k=k+1
            j=0
            fobj.writelines("\n")
            i=i+1
        #return "wrote matrix in required file"
    #def check(self):
     #   print self.elements
        #print self.file
      #  print self.list
       # print self.col
        #print self.row
m1=matrix('D:\mat1.txt')
m2=matrix('D:\mat2.txt')
#print type(m1)
print m1
print
print m2
#m3=matrix()
m3=m1+m2
#m3=matrix(m3)
#print m3
#print type(m3)
m3.write(m3,'D:\mat3.txt')
#print
print m3
```

except Exception,e:
    print e

Answer (score 1):

You should `return self` instead of `l`.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit, because i am not able to get desired output by returning self. no doubt it is now returning the matrix type but i want my list to convert to matrix type.

Comment: or if there is any other way to solve this problem . might be i have started creating function in wrong direction. The biggest problem i am facing to convert a variable into matrix datatype is, i have too give a file as input. might be the code architecture is wrong.

Comment: How exactly do you want your matrix to look?

Comment: the aim of the question is

Comment: i want to display the matrix in matrix format only as well as i am copying final output to a file by using write function.  i have taken m1 and m2 of matrix type i am using str function to display in matrix form now when i am adding two matrices m1 and m2 and storing in m3. and m3 is of type list. what i want is m3 should be of type matrix.so add function should return a matrix type. and once m3 will be of type matrix .i will call other function to write that matrix in a file. could you please correct me where i am doing wrong.